# SQL select IN clause from array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a list

```
$list = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$filter_list = join(", " $list);
select * from test where id_col=12 and try_col in ($filter_list);
```

Anybody could tell me how Can I do this.?

Comment: What does the "try in $list" part mean?

Comment: Please provide more information, which database are you using and how interact with it? mysql? mysqli? PDO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$list = array('a','b','c','d','e','f');
$filter_list = "'" . join("', '", $list) . "'";
$query = "select * from test where id=12 and try_col in ($filter_list)";
// select * from test where id=12 and try_col in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```

Note that this will fail if your array values contain `'`. Here is a workaround:

```
$list = array("a'a",'a\a','b','c','d','e','f');
$temp = array_map("addslashes", $list);
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=12 AND try_col in ('" . implode("','", $temp) . "')";
// SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=12 AND try_col in ('a\'a','a\\a','b','c','d','e','f')
```

Comment: You should also make sure to escape the values so they can be used properly in an SQL statement

Comment: `addslashes` should be quoted as a string. Also, its much better to use his database-specific escape function. There are several ways to exploit SQL injection when strings are quoted with `addslashes` and its not locale-aware. Also, the correct way to escape some characters could be different with different RDBMS. That's why I asked him about his database and the API he uses to talk with it.

Comment: I am using postgreSQL database.

Comment: Using PDO or the `pg_` functions?

Comment: @shesek: thanks, I thought I was writing jQuery code! Queue, as suggested by shesek I encourage you to use [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php). I do not have postgres extension so I couldn't test.